# Trouble with hg update when trying to checkout subrepo

Tags: svn, mercurial, subrepos

I have a **hg repository** with **svn subrepo**.

I've successfully cloned it to some machine and pulled newest revisions. Then I'm trying to update working dir to revision:

```
bwh1te@dev-machine:~/work/project_name$ hg pull
http authorization required
realm: HG Repository
user: bwh1te
password: 
pulling from https://hg.some-company.com/project_name
searching for changes
no changes found
bwh1te@dev-machine:~/work/project_name$ hg update -C RELEASE-2_50
abort: Получена ревизия 28463.
```

('Получена ревизия' means 'Checked out revision' in Russian) Abort because of what? Revision was successfully checked out! So I can't update because of some unknown causes.

I've also trying to checkout svn repo separately and it works:

```
bwh1te@dev-machine:~/somestuff/subrepo$ svn co svn+ssh://svn.some-company.com/.../trunk
A    trunk/dev
A    trunk/dev/main.cfg.xml
...
 U   trunk
Checked out revision 28549.
```

So:

1. Its possible to checkout svn subrepo separately
2. Its possible for me to `hg update` this repo on **another machines**
3. Its possible for **another users** to `hg update` this repo on the same machine
4. Svn checkout and checkout as subrepo (while `hg update`) returns different changesets!

Where can I search the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Russian letters in Subversion output.

A couple of words about my environment. My machine has a Ubuntu Linux 12.04 on board and `LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8` in my bash user profile. So some messages, like messages from Subversion were translated to local language, in this case Russian. I guess, Mercurial parse this messages and it did not expect some not English symbols (*only ASCII? only [A-Za-z0-9]?*)

My team-mate (*who had same problem and finally found solution*) have fixed this problem by creating additional alias for `svn`:

```
#!/bin/bash
LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/svn $@
```

Maybe it would be sufficient just to make `LC_ALL=` in bash user profile.